# Unable to append the matrix to the existing matrix in R

Tags: r

I am completely new to R and I am trying to write a formula for exponential weighted moving average. can anyone help me with this.

i.e [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC2t4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRYwJ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXhLz.png)

```
lambda<-0.7

z_i<-matrix(0,112,2)

for (i in 1:nrow(result1)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(result1)) {
  variance_covariance_z_i<- lambda*(1-(1-lambda)^(2*i))*in_control_covariance/(2-lambda)
  z_i[i,j] <-as.matrix(lambda*((result1[i,])-in_control_mean)+(1-lambda))z_i[i-1,j]
  z_i_all <-rbind(z_i_all,z_i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be mindful of the tags you attach to a question, this has nothing to do with the desktop IDE ([tag:rstudio]) nor the server-based IDE ([tag:rstudio-server]). Thanks.

Comment: Iteratively binding rows to a matrix (or `data.frame`) is a bad idea in the long run; while it works and logically makes sense, it scales poorly and will cause slowdowns in larger samples. See the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), specifically chapter 2, *"Growing Objects"*.

Comment: What do you expect the answer to be? You have not defined `in_control_covariance` or `in_control_mean`. You compute `variance_covariance_z_i` but you never use it in  your computations and it is overwritten on every pass through the loop.